Help understanding a mathematical oncology article
I'm trying to read the following article: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0198163#sec011, which describes a mathematical model of niche construction for cancer. However, I have virtually no background in applied math (e.g., differential equations), and I have a basic question.
The authors partition the tumor cells into four types, and assume (on pg. 5) that the populations of each type grow according to certain differential equations. In the "Separation of timescales" section on pg. 7, they explain how their approach involves finding the equilibria of the cell dynamics while holding the resource $R$ constant.

What is meant, mathematically, by "equilibria of the cell dynamics?"

Thank you.

This all seems very specific to the paper in question.  That is to say, they have some model in mind and those terms make sense in the context of that model.  But, of course, we have no idea what that model is.

Ah, I thought these were probably terms coming from differential equations theory, and the "model" is the system of equations on pg. 5. Also, am I crazy or are the mathematical derivations not included anywhere in the paper?

I'm assuming you are refering to the "Separation of timescales" section. What is done there is the quasi-steady state approximation (or assumption). When dealing with a system of differential equations, it is usually much easier to consider a system with a smaller number of them. If some variables change way faster and tend to their steady states, they can be assumed to be in such states and their value can be substituted into ohter equations.
What is meant by "equilibria of the cell dynamics", is the equilibira/steady states for the equations dealing with the cell dynamics. I didn't read much into the article, so I'm not sure which equations deal with cell dynamics and which in the resource dynamics, but the resource is assumed to change much slower. This means that the cells can be considered with constant resource R, and in turn the resource dynamics can be separately investigated with the cell variables in their steady states (if they tend to them - in general the behavior for large values of time).
Lastly, if you are concerned with what an equilibrium/steady state is, it is a value for which the derivative of the variable is equal to 0 and does not change (or all the derivatives in the system, but here it is meant for onbe variable I think). For example for the equation
$$\dot{x} = -x+1,$$
the steady state is obtained from $\dot{x} = 0 \iff x=1$. If there are multiple equations, for example
$$ \begin{aligned} \dot{x}&=-x+y, \\
\dot{y} &= -y + 2x + 1, \end{aligned}
$$
then the equilibrium for the variable $y$ would be $y=2x+1$, and for the variable $x$ $x=y$. When finding the equilibria for the whole system, these two equations have to be solved together. However, if we add some time scales, meaning
$$ \begin{aligned} \tau_x \dot{x}&=-x+y, \\
\tau_y \dot{y} &= -y + 2x + 1, \end{aligned}
$$
where $\tau_x, \tau_y \in \mathbb{R}_+$ are some positive real numbers, with some assumptions we can analyse the behavior of each variable separately. For example $\tau_x \ll \tau_y$ would mean that the variable $x$ changes way faster (on a smaller time scale). When investigating the behavior of $x$, $y$ could be assumed to be constant and when investigating the behavior of $y$, $x$ could be assumed to be in its steady state $x=y$, and the equation for $\dot{y}$ would be $\tau_y \dot{y} = -y +2y + 1 = y+1$. This is just a simple example, but the idea is the same in the article. This is a somewhat standard practice in mathematical modeling when dealing with a system of multiple differential equations, in which both fast- and slow-changing variables are incorporated.
